# Split text into chunks by ensuring the entireness of words

Tags: python, python-re

I have a bunch of text samples. Each sample has a different length, but all of them consist of >200 characters. I need to split each sample into approx 50 chara ters length substrings. To do so, I found this approach:

```
import re

def chunkstring(string, length):
    return re.findall('.{%d}' % length, string)
```

However, it splits a text by splitting words. For example, the phrase "I have <...> icecream. <...>" can be split into "I have <...> icec" and "ream. <...>".

This is the sample text:

> This paper proposes a method that allows non-parallel many-to-many
> voice conversion by using a variant of a generative adversarial
> network called StarGAN.

I get this result:

```
['This paper proposes a method that allows non-paral',
 'lel many-to-many voice conversion by using a varia',
 'nt of a generative adversarial network called Star']
```

But ideally I would like to get something similar to this result:

```
['This paper proposes a method that allows non-parallel',
 'many-to-many voice conversion by using a variant',
 'of a generative adversarial network called StarGAN.']
```

How could I adjust the above-given code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this sound like task for [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) built-in module, example using your data

```
import textwrap
text = "This paper proposes a method that allows non-parallel many-to-many voice conversion by using a variant of a generative adversarial network called StarGAN."
print(textwrap.fill(text,55))
```

output

```
This paper proposes a method that allows non-parallel
many-to-many voice conversion by using a variant of a
generative adversarial network called StarGAN.
```

You will probably need some trials to get value which suits your needs best. If you need `list` of `str`s use `textwrap.wrap` i.e. `textwrap.wrap(text,55)`

Comment: Why do you use `55` and not `50`?

Comment: @Fluxy using 50 result in getting 4 pieces, whilst output presented in question has 3 pieces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.{0,50}\S*` in order to keep matching eventual further non-space characters (`\S`).

I specified `0` as lowerbound since otherwise you'd risk missing the last substring.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/71gDQT/1).

**EDIT:**

For excluding the trailing empty chunk, use `.{1,50}\S*`, in order to force it to match at least one character.

If you also want to automatically strip the side spaces, use `\s*(.{1,50}\S*)`.

Comment: This is a very good solution. However, the string list returned from re.findall() could have a leading (unwanted) space which can obviously be stripped

Comment: Great! It seems to also return an empty chunk at the end `''`. How can I drop it out using regex?

Comment: @Fluxy Use 1 as lowerbound ;-)

Comment: @Fluxy If you want also to automatically strip the spaces, use `\s*(.{1,50}\S*)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def nearestDelimiter(txt,  cur):
    delimiters = " ;:.!?-—"          
    if(txt[cur] in delimiters) :          
          return cur
    else:
        i=cur
        while ( i>=0 ):
            if (txt[i] in delimiters) :                    
                        return i
            i=i-1
    return 0


def splitText(sentence,chunkLength):
     cursor = 0  
     curlng = chunkLength
     lst = []
     while (curlng < len(sentence)):
         curlng = nearestDelimiter(sentence, curlng)       
         substr = (sentence[cursor : curlng]).strip()
         cursor = curlng        
         curlng = (cursor+chunkLength) if (cursor+chunkLength<len(sentence)) else len(sentence)            
         lst.append(substr)
     lst.append((sentence[cursor : curlng]).strip())
     return lst


txt = "This paper proposes a method that allows non-parallel many-to-many voice conversion by using a variant of a generative adversarial network called StarGAN."

cvv = splitText(txt,50)
for cv in cvv:
    print(cv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a .txt on my desktop and wanted it divided into 50 equal smaller files based on word count. I saved the following python script as a plain txt file:

```
import os
import sys

def split_txt_file(file_path, num_files):
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

words = content.split()
total_words = len(words)
words_per_file = total_words // num_files

for i in range(num_files):
    start = i * words_per_file
    end = (i + 1) * words_per_file if i < num_files - 1 else None

    with open(f"{file_path[:-4]}_part{i+1}.txt", 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(' '.join(words[start:end]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
file_path = os.path.expanduser(sys.argv[1])
num_files = int(sys.argv[2])
split_txt_file(file_path, num_files)
```

Then navigated to my desktop in terminal, and ran this:

```
python3 split_txt.py.txt '~/Desktop/rawText.txt' 50
```